# Corona lua: How do I attach a .txt data file saved to system.DocumentsDirectory to an email?

Tags: file, email, text, coronasdk

Corona lua: How do I attach a data file that is saved to the system directory to an email? An image of the data.txt file shows up in the email pop up on an iPad after I build, but doesn't get attached although the email is sent. Images go fine. I used "text", "plain", and "text/plain" as the mime type. If you can help with this, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: I forgot that I had to actually write to the file from within the built app to get it to register in the System Directory.D'OH!!! Please ignore the question with my apologies!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                     -- Creating the text file --
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
local filePath_Type = system.pathForFile( "myTextFile.txt", system.DocumentsDirectory )
local file = io.open( filePath_Type, "r" )
if file then
  io.close( file )
else
  --Create an empty file--  
  local path_Type = system.pathForFile( "myTextFile.txt", system.DocumentsDirectory )
  local file = io.open( path_Type, "w+b" )
  file:write("My data inside file")
  io.close( file )
end

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                      -- Now, to email this file --
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function showMailPicker()
  -- Create mail options --
  local options =
    {
      to = { "me@me.com",},
      subject = "Subject Text",
      body = "Email Body",
      attachment =
        {
          { baseDir=system.DocumentsDirectory, filename="myTextFile.txt", type="text" },
        },
  }
   -- Send mail --
  native.showPopup("mail", options)
end

submitButton = display.newImageRect("myButton.png",100,40)
submitButton.x = 160
submitButton.y = 240
submitButton:addEventListener("tap",showMailPicker)
```

Keep Coding.............. :)

Comment: Thanks so much, krs...!!! I will definitely have to keep coding. This was my first email attachment that wasn't an image shot from within the app where the system directory folder had to be written to in order to even test it. OVERSIGHTS...

Comment: Did it work for you? I've to add group:insert(submitButton) after submitButton:addEventListener("tap",showMailPicker)

Comment: @Irishgirl: Yes, this will do the purpose. What do you mean with `I've to add group:insert(submitButton)`..? It is only about adding your `submitButton` to a `displayGroup`. You can do that as per need. If you have more doubt, feel free to post with some code...